# On the coloring number of small graphs with small cliques

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-colouring, extremal-combinatorics

Given a parameter $k$, and a graph $G$ with $O(k^2)$ vertices that has a maximum clique with $\le k$ vertices, I want to investigate the maximum number of colors $C(k)$ needed to properly color $G$, i.e $\chi(G)\le C(k)$.

Using Mycielski's graphs, one can show that this number should be at least $k+\log k$.

It is known that for any integer $c$ there is a triangle-free graph that has chromatic number $c$. However in all these constructions, as far as I know, the size of these graphs is a rapidly increasing function of $c$.

I conjecture that $C(k)=\Theta(k)$ and I would be really grateful for any helpful references related to this question.

Comment: Do you mean the size (number of edges) or the order (number of vertices) to be $O(k^2)$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I actually meant "order". I make an edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uniformly random $k^2$-vertex graphs have clique size $O(\log k)$, well under $k$, and independent set size also $O(\log k)$, implying that their chromatic number is $\Omega(k^2/\log k)$.

As for $k^2$-vertex triangle-free graphs, their chromatic number can be $\Theta(k/\sqrt{\log k})$ (and not higher); see Kim, Jeong Han (1995),
"The Ramsey number $R(3,t)$ has order of magnitude $t^2/\log t$", *Random Structures & Algorithms* 7 (3): 173–207, [doi:10.1002/rsa.3240070302](https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.3240070302)

If by "size" you mean edges rather than vertices, then the maximum chromatic number of triangle-free $k^2$-edge graphs is $\Theta((k/\log k)^{2/3})$. See Nilli, A. (2000), "Triangle-free graphs with large chromatic numbers", *Discrete Mathematics* 211(1–3): 261–262, [doi:10.1016/S0012-365X(99)00109-0](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(99)00109-0).

Comment: To add to this, for David's third comment, it was actually Poljak and Tuza (1994) who first showed this (modulo Kim's result): 

S. Poljak and Z. Tuza. Bipartite subgraphs of triangle-free graphs. SIAM J. Discrete Math., 7(2):307–313, 1994.

Moreover, Gimbel and Thomassen (2000) were contemporaneous to Noga:

J. Gimbel and C. Thomassen. Coloring triangle-free graphs with fixed
size. Discrete Math., 219(1-3):275–277, 2000.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Mycielski graphs, I guess you only need an upper bound on the chromatic number, as a function of the graph size. Such a bound is mentioned e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167258/inequality-between-chromatic-number-and-number-of-edges-of-a-graph), showing that a graph of size $O(k^2)$ has chromatic number $O(k)$, which proves that $C(k) \in \Theta(k)$.

*EDIT: This answer is invalidated by an update to the original question.*